# Provisioned XlstViewWebPart in root web gives me List does not exist when delete

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Consider following:

I have an Admin sub site which have all lists and Document Libraries, I provision most of Document Libraries in the Root web programmatically using XlstViewWebPart, when I try to select an item and delete it using delete button on the ribbon I get:

***The server has encountered the following error(s):
List does not exist. The page you selected contains a list that does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.***

But if delete the item from item popup menu, it is working fine and deleted !!!!

Platform: SharePoint Server 2010 SP1, VS 2010, CU June 2012

Thanks in advance

========================================

## Update (My Code to provision web parts)

```
            Dim _web As SPWeb = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb

        Try
            'Get refrence to publishing web
            Dim _pubWeb As PublishingWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(_web)
            Dim WPM As Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPLimitedWebPartManager

            If _pubWeb IsNot Nothing Then
                'Loop each publishing page in the web
                'Check out the file
                'If the current page have CustomWebPart (It is an Custom System Page), Then
                'If XsltListViewWebPart is not provisiond (double check in case of click the button more than one time), then
                'Create an XsltListViewWebPart
                'Assign properties of the new XsltListViewWebPart with Document Lib. Name and Admin web
                'Add the new XsltListViewWebPart to the current page in the loop
                For Each curPage As PublishingPage In _pubWeb.GetPublishingPages()
                    If curPage.ListItem.File.RequiresCheckout AndAlso curPage.ListItem.File.CheckOutType = SPFile.SPCheckOutType.None Then curPage.CheckOut()

                    WPM = curPage.ListItem.File.GetLimitedWebPartManager(System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared)

                    Dim CustomWebPart As CustomWebPart = WPM.WebParts.OfType(Of CustomWebPart)().FirstOrDefault()

                    If CustomWebPart IsNot Nothing Then
                        If CustomWebPart.DocLibName.ToLower = Constants.List.MeetingSchedular.ListName.ToLower Then Continue For

                        Dim web As SPWeb = _web.Site.RootWeb.Webs(Constants.WebNames.AdminWeb) 'Get Admin Web
                        Dim LVWP As WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart = WPM.WebParts.OfType(Of WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart)().FirstOrDefault()

                        If LVWP Is Nothing Then
                            LVWP = New WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart

                            Dim lst As SPList = web.Lists(CustomWebPart.DocLibName)

                            With LVWP
                                .WebId = web.ID
                                .ViewGuid = lst.DefaultView.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper()
                                .ListName = lst.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper()
                                .ListId = lst.ID
                                .ListUrl = "/Admin/" + CustomWebPart.DocLibName
                                .TitleUrl = "/Admin/" + CustomWebPart.DocLibName
                                .ChromeType = System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PartChromeType.None
                                .AllowClose = False
                                .AllowEdit = True
                                .AllowMinimize = True
                                .AllowConnect = True
                            End With

                            _web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = True
                            WPM.AddWebPart(LVWP, "MainZone", 0)

                            curPage.Update()
                            _web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = False
                        End If

                        curPage.CheckIn("By cmdProvisionWebParts_Click")
                        curPage.ListItem.File.Publish("By cmdProvisionWebParts_Click")
                    End If
                Next
            End If
            RegisterNotification("Provision Web Parts Completed successfully")
        Catch ex As Exception
            SiteHelper.WriteErrors("Custom_Settings.ProvisioningRootWebParts", ex)
            RegisterNotification("Error: " + ex.Message)
        End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, the error happens because your list belongs to another site (or subsite) and SP says you, that it doesn't have the list.
Try to create the list in your site and delete again.
And if it wouldn't work, please show us your XlstViewWebPart code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes the list belongs to sub site and provisioned by code in the root web. I Update my post with code.